# ASP.NET MVC: Applying CSS-Style for validation on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application I want to do the following thing, if the user clicks the button to submit his data I want to apply a certain style if an input validation error occurs. Till now im struggling how I could do this, since Im pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, HTML, etc. So what I did I created a CSS-File, that looks like that:

ErrorHighlighting.css:

```
.field-validation-error {background-color: #ffb3b3;}
.field-validation-valid {display: none;}
.input-validation-error {background-color: #ffb3b3;}
.select.input-validation-valid { display: none;}
.select.input-validation-error { border: 1px solid #f00; background-color: #ffb3b3; }
.validation-summary-error {font-weight: bold; color: #ffb3b3;}
.validation-summary-valid {display: none}
```

The HTML signature of my button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">Save it!</button>
```

So what did I try till now, to solve my problem, I tried it with JavaScript and getelementbyid to apply testwise the input validation error on that button click, but that did not work, nothing happend when I click the button. So at the moment Im not sure, how I could apply this or if its possible at all, so I would be thankful for a hint or information, how I could do this.

Thanks everyone and have a nice weekend!

Comment: There is no point have styles such as `.field-validation-valid {display: none;}` - that is the class applied to the `<span>` element generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` - if it has the `class="field-validation-valid"` it contain no text so `display:none;` is pointless. But `.field-validation-error {background-color: #ffb3b3;}` works just fine. You do not need any javascript for this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi again and thanks for answer and help. So I will remove this from my css file. But Im still wondering, can I make this work, if a user hits a button that a certain style for input errors appears? Because I will have another form later with multiple buttons where I could use something like that.

Comment: If you have `.field-validation-error {background-color: #ffb3b3;}` in your css file and one of the properties is invalid, and you have an associated `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`, then the message will be displayed with the colored background. I'm not sure why your claiming it does not work (and I have no idea what you mean by another form with multiple buttons)